# Issue regarding the change event of textfield in titanium

Tags: android, titanium

I have the following code

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
var newTF = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    top : 20,
    hintText : "new text field under "+(i+1)+" text field"
    width : '100%',
    id:args.obj.fields[i].id
});

   $.textFieldView1.add(newTF);
 }

  newTF.addEventListener('change',function(e){
    if(e.source.getValue=='entered value'){
      //do something
    }
    else{
      //do something
    }
});
```

Now the problem which I am facing is I am getting the last created textfield(i.e id of last created textfield).So I am not able change trigger any changes on previously created textfields.Its like previous id of textfield is overlapped by latest one.

Can anyone help on this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var newTF = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        newTF[i] = Ti.UI.createTextField({
            //top : 20,
            hintText : "new text field under " + (i + 1) + " text field",
            width : '100%',
            id :i+1,
        });
        //newTF[i].addEventListener('');
        newTF[i].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            Ti.API.info('e is'+JSON.stringify(e));
         if (e.source.getValue == 'entered value') {
                // //do something
         } else {
                // //do something
         }
        });
        $.laynout.add(newTF[i]);
    }
```

Comment: `newTF[i].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
if(newTF[j].getValue()>=minValue && newTF[j].getValue()<=maximumValue)
{

    alert('display something');
}
});`


It is not going in if()
Can you please help me regarding this?